# Find invalid values of $Y$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, functions, proof-writing, systems-of-equations

Let $$Y = (\textbf{a})\cdot x_1 + (\textbf{a}+1)\cdot x_2 + (\textbf{a}+2)\cdot x_3 + (\textbf{a}+3)\cdot x_4 + . . . + (\textbf{a}+n)\cdot x_n$$

Where $x_1,x_2,x_3.... x_n$ are all positive integers $(\ge 0), n\ge 1$ and $a\ge1$.

**NOTE**: $x_1,x_2,x_3,... ,x_n$ can be any positive integers $(\ge0)$ and must not be distinct.

Given the value of $\textbf{a}$ count all possible values $Y\ge 1$ where there are no possible values of $x_1,x_2,x_3,... ,x_n$.

I just thought about this problem and I have been trying to think of a solution to this problem but all I could come up with is trying every possible value. Please help me solve.

Comment: Please use mathJax!

Comment: @OllyReynolds please what is mathJax

Comment: You wrote "positive integers(>=0)". Do you mean positive, i.e., $\gt 0$, or non-negative, i.e., $\ge 0$?

Comment: In your note I think you mean that  the $x_i$ need not be distinct (rather than must not be distinct), otherwise they would not be  given different variable names. What you have written means the opposite. Or perhaps you mean that they must be distinct. Either way, what is currently written doesn't seem to make sense.